# При запуске Eclipse каждый раз запускается DLTK

Tags: eclipse

Добрый день!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, установил Eclipse Luna для работы над сайтами (сборка под PHP), поставил кучу плагинов, всё настроил, всё хорошо. Но вот появилась такая проблема. Каждый раз при запуске программы плагин DLTK начинет заново индексировать все мои проекты, при этом удаляет и создаёт заново файлы индекса из /workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql.h2/
Это очень неудобно, проектов становится больше, и каждый запуск DLTK отнимает у меня минут 15 рабочего времени, т.к. пока работает DLTK, код писать невозможно, всё страшно тормозит.

Все программы, автоматически очищающие кеш с компа, удалены. Собственно это делает сам DLTK при запуске eclipse.

Comment: @maler1988, любая IDE при запуске производит переиндексацию файлов. Просто закрывайте проекты, над которыми не работаете.

Comment: Дома он у меня так не делает, только для новых проектов.